# SAS General Estimating Equations (marginal means) code to R code?

Tags: r, sas, glm

I would like to convert the following SAS GEE marginal means model code to R. How can I do that for instance with the R packages (geepack OR gee)?

The **SAS code runs correctly** and produces desired output. The **R code is my incomplete and probably not correct/complete** attempt in R.

The data to use (**seizx**) in R is provided.

The results from SAS code is attached as a screenshot.

Working SAS CODE:

```
proc genmod data=tt.seizx descending; 
class trt time  id; 
model y = trt|age  x / dist = gamma link=log; 
repeated subject=id / type=exch within=time ; * 
title 'gee with exchangeable corr structure';
run;
```

Attempted in R using geeglm function (library(geepack)), but incomplete and untested

```
library(geepack)
btb_geepack <- geeglm(dayslost2 ~ trt*age + x, 
                      data = seizx, 
                      id = id,
                      family = ???, 
                      corstr = "exchangeable")
```

Sample data to use in R

```
# Sample data.
seizx <- structure(list(trt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), age = c(31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
57L, 57L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L), time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), y = c(11L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 66L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 
21L, 27L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 52L, 40L, 20L, 
23L, 12L, 23L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 6L, 0L, 52L, 26L, 
12L, 6L, 22L, 33L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 42L, 
7L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 87L, 16L, 24L, 10L, 9L, 50L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
18L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 111L, 37L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 18L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 20L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 28L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 55L, 18L, 24L, 
76L, 25L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 47L, 13L, 
15L, 13L, 12L, 76L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 8L, 38L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 19L, 
0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 24L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 31L, 22L, 17L, 19L, 16L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 
11L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 67L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 41L, 4L, 18L, 2L, 5L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 
46L, 11L, 14L, 25L, 15L, 36L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 38L, 19L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 36L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 151L, 102L, 65L, 72L, 63L, 22L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 42L, 
8L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 32L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 56L, 18L, 11L, 28L, 13L, 
24L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 22L, 1L, 23L, 19L, 
8L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L), t = c(8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2), x = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), age2 = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L)), reshapeLong = list(varying = list(
    c("base", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")), v.names = "y", idvar = "id", 
    timevar = "time"), row.names = c(NA, -295L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: `geeglm(I(y + 1) ~ factor(trt, 1:0)*age + x, data = seizx, id = id, family = Gamma(link = 'log'), corstr = "exchangeable")` gets you most of the way there but a little off.. does sas allow 0s in your y variable? also `dayslost2` is not defined in your data

Comment: @rawr Your right, SAS does not (i think) allow zeros, so you can convert all the zeros to 1. Apologies, the "dayslost2" should be "y" variable in the R dataset

Comment: Do you know how I can add something similar to the "within=" statement on the SAS code to the R formular ? The within statement does the following according to documentation: within=where-condition
After fitting the model, margins and marginal effects are computed by averaging only over the observations meeting the specified condition. More details here: https://support.sas.com/kb/63/038.html

Comment: no I'm not sure, you could scan the vignette and see if there is something you're looking for documented in there